# Data not getting stored in database but no error

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I wrote the following code

**PHP**

```
<?php
    try{$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');}
    catch (Exception $e){die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());}

    $req = $bdd->prepare('insert into signup    
           (email,   password,   service,    phone) 
    values(:email,  :password,  :service,   :phone_number)  ');

    $req->execute(array(
    'email'        => htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']),
    'password'     => htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']),
    'service'      => htmlspecialchars($_POST['service']),
    'phone_number' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone_number'])));

    echo 'Well done';
    print_r($_POST);

?>
```

I have a "Well done" message and

```
     Array ( [email] => test@test.test [password] => test[confirm_password] => test[service] => pizza [phone_number] => 01234 )
```

when I execute my code. But nothing in my DB.
Where is my mistake?

Comment: You shouldn't `htmlspecialchars` input into a database. PDO takes care of SQL escaping for you, no other escaping is required at this point. Do `htmlspecialchars` when you display the value in HTML. So: `echo "<h1>" . htmlspecialchars($title) . "</h1>";`

Comment: Add `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened and error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Put your `catch` before the `echo 'Well done'`

Comment: Make sure `$req` is an instance of `PDOStatement`, and as Fred-ii- said: set `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to throw exceptions in case of any mishap

Comment: What is your DB schema?

Comment: Another possibility is that you've chosen the wrong table to insert into, even though the one you're trying to insert into exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only catching an exception if connection fails, not when actually inserting using execute. Either use two @ try/catch, or expand the scope of your try & move your catch.

```
<?php
    try
       {
          $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');

          $req = $bdd->prepare('insert into signup    
                 (email,   password,   service,    phone) 
          values(:email,  :password,  :service,   :phone_number)  ');

          $req->execute(array(
          'email'        => htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']),
          'password'     => htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']),
          'service'      => htmlspecialchars($_POST['service']),
          'phone_number' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone_number'])));

          echo 'Well done';
          print_r($_POST);
       }

    catch (Exception $e)
    {
         die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

?>
```